# Функция, принимающая указатель на другую функцию

Tags: c++, c

Функция принимает в аргумент указатель на другую функцию. Как правильно объявить прототип?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*С++*: посредством `typedef`

Неформально:

```
typedef ReturnType(*FunctionPtr)(Parm1Type, Parm2Type, ...);
```

Прототип:

```
typedef void(*FunctionPtr)();
void func(const FunctionPtr& functionPtr);
```

Пример кода:

```
void parmFunc(){}

typedef void(*FunctionPtr)();
void func(const FunctionPtr& functionPtr){ functionPtr(); }

int main()
{
    func(&parmFunc);
}
```

---

*С++11*: посредством `using`

Неформально:

```
using FunctionPtr = ReturnType(*)(Parm1Type, Parm2Type, ...);
```

Прототип:

```
using FunctionPtr = void(*)();
void func(const FunctionPtr& functionPtr);
```

Пример кода:

```
void parmFunc(){}

using FunctionPtr = void(*)();
void func(const FunctionPtr& functionPtr){ functionPtr(); }

int main()
{
    func(&parmFunc);                         // вариант 1
    func([](){/* code of your function */}); // вариант 2
}
```

---

*C++11*: посредством `std::function`

Неформально:

```
using FunctionPtr = std::function<ReturnType(Parm1Type, Parm2Type, ...)>;
```

Прототип:

```
#include <functional>

using FunctionPtr = std::function<void()>;
void func(const FunctionPtr& functionPtr);
```

Пример кода:

```
#include <functional>

void parmFunc(){}

using FunctionPtr = std::function<void()>;
void func(const FunctionPtr& functionPtr){ functionPtr(); }

int main()
{
    func(&parmFunc);                         // вариант 1
    func(std::bind(parmFunc));               // вариант 2
    func([](){/* code of your function */}); // вариант 3
}
```

---

Если ваша функция должна возвращать значение и/или принимать параметры, то смотрите *неформальное* описание в данном ответе.

Comment: Можно cюда добавить функцию и указатель на нее?

Answer (score 1):

Проще и понятнее для меня оказалось

```
объявление указателя на функцию1
тип_возвращ_значен_функц1(*func1ptr)(тип_аргумента1, тип_аргумента2);

и его инициализация
func1ptr = &func1;

объявление функции2, принимающей наш указатель
тип_возвращ_значен_функц2 func2(тип_возвращ_значен_функц1(*func1ptr)(тип_аргумента1, тип_аргумента2));
```

А теперь по человечески

```
void func1(int, double); //функция1
void (*func1Prt)(int, double); //указатель на функцию1
func1Ptr = &func1;

int func2(void (*fp)(int, double)); //объявление функции2 (в параметрах только один указатель!)
func2(func1Ptr); //передача параметра(нашего указателя на функцию1)
```