# Функция, принимающая или возвращающая саму себя

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

В связи с вопросом о том, [как описать тип функции, принимающей в качестве аргумента другую функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510599/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E), вспомнил вопрос, разбиравшийся Саттером - как объявить тип функции, которая принимает или возвращает саму себя (т.е. функцию того же типа). По тем временам решения как такового не было, были какие-то костыли и не более того. Изменилась ли как-то ситуация в C++11 и C++14? Можно ли более-менее честно объявить такую функцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать класс с оператором (). Выглядит неотличимо от функции (кстати, именно так и реализованны лямбда-функции):

```
#include "stdio.h"

int k = 0;

class MyFun{
  public:
  auto operator () (){
    k++;
    printf("Function called: %d\n",k);
    return *this;
  }
};

main(){
  MyFun fun;
  auto x = fun()()()()()(); 
}
```

Вывод:

```
Function called: 1
Function called: 2
Function called: 3
Function called: 4
Function called: 5
Function called: 6
```

Comment: Да. но, кстати, было можно сделать и тогда, при старом стандарте - просто вместо `auto` использовать `MyFun&`. Хотя, конечно, это не совсем функция, но все же... Словом, нужно сесть и хорошо подумать :), так что пока - спасибо!