# Какой тип у рекурсивной лямбды?

Tags: c++, lambda

Это код определяет рекурсивный факториал с помощью игрек-комбинатора. Он компилируется и работает, действительно вычисляет факториал:

```
auto y_comb = [](auto f, int n) { return f(f, n); };

auto fact_rec = [](auto f, int n) -> int {
    return (n > 0) ? n * f(f, n - 1) : 1;
};

auto fact = [y_comb, fact_rec](int n) { return y_comb(fact_rec, n); };
```

Я хочу переписать этот код в виде функций, но не могу подобрать тип для функции-аналога `fact_rec`.

Какой тип у лямбды `fact_rec`?

Что нужно написать в std::function чтобы поместить туда `fact_rec`?

Можно ли этот код переписать в виде обычных функций, не лямбд?

Comment: Понимаете, если вы используете обычные функции, незачем передавать саму функцию как аргумент — она известна и так. Все эти хитровывернутости упрощаются, и получается `int fact_rec(int n) { return (n > 0) ? n * fact_rec(n - 1) : 1; }`...

Comment: @Harry, я привык что если я написал лямбду без капчи, то я могу переписать её в виде функции. Но я не могу, так как не умею придумать тип функции. (Я знаю что есть есть имена, все эти приёмчики не нужны, вопрос про другое).

Comment: @Harry, вот вам ещё пример. Конечный автомат удобно описать так: каждому состоянию соответствует функция. Вы её вызываете, она возвращает функцию того же типа что и она сама - другое состояние. В C было невозможно объявить такую функцию без использования `void *`. В C++ появилась возможность вместо функций сделать объекты с `operator()`. Кажется, теперь я могу сделать конечный автомат на лямбдах. Кажется, я не могу переписать его в виде функций.

Comment: Боюсь, что такое рекурсивное определение прописать не удастся...

Comment: @Harry, следовательно лямбды более выразительны чем функции. Я никак не ожидал подобного.

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/510653/195342 Кстати, похоже, что отсутствия захвата недостаточно для того, чтоб получалась функция...

Comment: Кстати, судя по сгенеренному VC++ ассемблерному листингу, создается таки класс с оператором (), а не функция, как бывает, когда нет захвата...

Comment: *"не могу подобрать тип для функции-аналога fact_rec"* - и не сможете, потому что аналогом шаблонной лямбды является шаблон функции

Comment: @user7860670, шаблон реализуется для конкретных типов. Я не могу выписать функцию для конкретных типов.